# Springboot webflux with custom openapi spec file fails

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, openapi, reactive, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am trying to point my springboot application at custom api spec file with the below configuration

1. Added **api.yml** to **resources > static folder**.
2. Updated the springboot properties.

```yaml
spring-doc:
  swagger-ui:
    path: /swagger-ui.html
    enabled: true
    url: "/api.yml"
    defaultModelsExpandDepth: -1
  api-docs:
    path: /api-docs
    enabled: true
```

I am using the below dependency

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

I am using the openApi Spec sample from here
https://editor.swagger.io/?url=https://crop-pal.org/oas3/oas3.yaml

Eventually I get the error

[image]

Checked the documentation without much help. Can you point me what I am doing incorrectly or is it not supported for webflux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find a decent solution for this issue finally. The catch was that my application was a Spring Cloud Gateway Application.

Having said that the solution was clearly detailed in the blog

https://medium.com/@pubuduc.14/swagger-openapi-specification-3-integration-with-spring-cloud-gateway-part-2-1d670d4ab69a

Also added routing configurations via properties after adding respective swagger configs for the target microservices and every thing worked fine.

Comment: So then @varad  did you abandon trying to set `url: "/api.yml"` via the properties file? I have read docs [here](https://springdoc.org/#what-is-a-proper-way-to-set-up-swagger-ui-to-use-provided-spec-yml) and [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation) and nothing shows you how to create your own spec file (like api.yml) instead of relying on annotations or the programmatic approach.

Comment: In a way yes because I had to map multiple microservice via gateway. Hence this was a better approach where I get a dropdown of items which I can show on the swagger page.

Answer (score 1):

After wasting a ton of time, my issue ended up being that I needed to add `/api.yml` to my `WebSecurityConfig`(kotlin):

```
authorizeHttpRequests.requestMatchers(
    "/v3/api-docs/**",
    "/swagger-ui/**",
    "/api.yml",
).permitAll()
```